# How can I get the list of guilds my discord bot is in?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to know if I can get a list of guild IDs my bot is in. Basically, a command that returns a mesage containing all of the guild IDs the bot is currently in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Discord JS v12

```js
message.channel.send(client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id).join(", \n"));
```

## Discord JS v11

```js
message.channel.send(client.guilds.map(guild => guild.id).join(", \n"));
```

Comment: There's an error: ``(node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined``

Comment: Looks like you are using Discord JS v11. (You should update to V12.) Please try the second code I provided.